# How to upgrade from Ubuntu amd 64bit to intel 64bit?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, intel, compatibility, amd-processor

I've been using Ubuntu 12.10 for about a year and half now on my laptop with an intel processor. When I installed it I was dumb enough to commit the mistake of downloading a **amd 64bit** version of the OS instead of an  **intel 64bit** version. It actually works ok sometimes, but I think that I might be forcing my processor since it's using the wrong drivers, and Ubuntu sometimes randomly freezes when I have just few programs open and I end up having to force restart it. 
My question is, is it possible to upgrade to a **intel 64bit** version of Ubuntu, without loosing most of the programs I have installed and personal files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

AMD were first to produce a commercial 64bit CPU architecture aimed at normal users rather than the server market. As a result, `amd64` has come to be used to mean any 64bit architecture. There is no such thing as `intel64`, the [possible names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) are `x86-64`,`x86_64`,`x64`, and `AMD64x86_64` but they all refer to the same architecture.

You can test this by running `uname -m`. On my system, for example, with an intel i7 CPU, I get:

```
x86_64
```

So, any issues you are having are not because you installed the wrong version. I suggest you post a new question, explaining your issues and we'll see if we can figure it out.

Comment: And from the release notes for the installers: "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD: Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead."

Comment: @terdon thank you for the answer sr. turns out that I'm still dumb lol, living and learning.

Comment: @Yuran do not confuse ignorance with stupidity. The first is easily solved while the latter will dog you for a lifetime :).

Answer (score 0):

They are the same thing. From [Ubuntu's help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit):

> Each manufacturer has a different name for 64-bit, such as: AMD's AMD64 and Intel's IA-32e (later EM64T). We use AMD64 to refer to all implementations.

However, there is another 64-bit Intel architecture named [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64), also known as IA-64. Itanium desktop machines are very rare, and that architecture hasn't been supported since version 10.04 of Ubuntu. It was discontinued due to a [lack of developer interest](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2010-August/000441.html).